# Как сделать генератор в словаре для вывода N записей за раз?

Tags: python, классы, dict, итераторы, генераторы

Есть класс AddressBook который наследуется от UserDict. Как мне в методе Iterator сделать генератор по записям словаря и за одну итерацию возвращать по n записей? Сначала я пытался написать **iter** и **next**, но потом понял что он наследуется и у него уже есть эти методы. Поэтому нужно написать это в методе Iterator,  но пока что не понимаю как это сделать потому что генераторы и итераторы сложно даются мне. Также я пытался брать срезы до n, но это не список. В закомментированом коде я сделал ключи и значения в виде списков, в которых можно брать срезы, но это тоже не то - мне же нужен вывод в виде словаря. В общем объясните как это можно сделать пожалуйста.

```
class AddressBook(UserDict):

    address_book = {}

    def iterator(self, n):
        if not self.data:
            raise StopIteration

        records_to_return = self.data[:n]
        self.data = self.data[n:]
        #a = list(self.data.keys())
        #b = list(self.data.values())
        #print(a[:n])
        #print(b[:n])
        for record in self.data:
            print(record, '???')
```

Comment: self.data - это доступ к элементам словаря. В классах, которые являются наследниками от UserDict используется такой формат чтобы работать с данными. Address_Book это обычный словарь. Суть вопроса в создании генератора, который выводит элементы словаря в кол-ве n, где n - число от пользователя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chunks` принимает на вход любую последовательность, которую можно итерировать (например, `address_book.items()`), и разбивает её на фрагменты не более `n` штук в каждом. Метод `iterator` использует её чтобы выдать `self.data` кусочками по `n` штук.

Документация по [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).

```
import itertools


def chunks(seq, n):
    it = iter(seq)
    while True:
        t = tuple(itertools.islice(it, n))
        if len(t) == 0:
            break
        yield t


class AddressBook(UserDict):

    address_book = {}

    def iterator(self, n):
        for c in chunks(self.data, n):
            yield c
```

`iterator` можно записать по-другому:

```
    def iterator(self, n):
        return chunks(self.data, n):
```